# Security and API implementation - REST

Tags: .net, django, security, api, rest

I'm implementing an API using Django. One 1 service should be able to access 1 API url.

I am wondering if there are any popular security practices that go beyond using username/password and SSL?

Is using sequential signature generation a popular practice?

Comment: What threats are you trying to mitigate (or what problems are you trying to solve) that aren't solved by "username/password and SSL"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use [django-piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home). It uses OAuth for authorization.

Answer (score 0):

do not forget this Django REST framework:

[django-rest-framework.org](http://django-rest-framework.org)

I switched to this framework after trying tastypie for a while.